# Vue-router param not updating with back button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, back-button

I am using a param, and when I push the param using `this.$router.push()` it works.

```
routes: {
  path: ':stepId?',
  name: 'stepper'
}
```

BUT, I am also watching $route inside a component in order to catch the value of the param changing ([As described in the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)):

```js
watch: {
  $route: {
    handler: function(to, from) {
      const newStepId = (to.params && to.params.stepId) || this.steps[0].id;
      const initial = !from;
      if (initial || newStepId !== from.params.stepId) {
        this.goToStep(newStepId, initial);
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

However when I *use the back button*, either the `to` section of the route inside the `watch: $route` doesn't have any param, just the path OR the watch doesn't even run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was adding the $watch in the created() method.

```
  created() {
    this.$watch("$route",() => { 
    // this.$route.query is watched now as expected
   }, 
   { immediate: true });
  }
```

Still a bit unclear to me though why putting it in mounted or like what you did doesn't work

Comment: Interesting! It could be a slight difference in where immediate watchers are run and when the created hook gets run. i will look into that